# flatten a nested array of objects using RxJS

Tags: arrays, rxjs, flatten

our data structure is a nested array with objects

```
interface dtModel {
  id: number;
  permission: number;
  childs: dtModel[];
}

const data: dtModel[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    permission: 2,
    childs: [
      {
        id: 2,
        permission: 1,
        childs: [
          {
            id: 3,
            permission: 3,
            childs: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    permission: 1,
    childs: [
      {
        id: 5,
        permission: 2,
        childs: [
          {
            id: 6,
            permission: 3,
            childs: [
              {
                id: 7,
                permission: 1,
                childs: [],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I tried with help of RxJs to create a flattened array like this which is I'm not succeeded yet

```
[
  {id:1,permission:2},
  {id:2,permission:1},
  {id:3,permission:3},
  {id:4,permission:1},
  {id:5,permission:2},
  {id:6,permission:3},
  {id:7,permission:1}
]
```

I tried to do that with help of 'reduce' but because my childs' property does not always have the same length I couldn't do that with this approach.

```
of(data)
  .pipe(
    map((items: dtModel[]) => {
      return items.reduce((res, curr) => {
        res.push({ id: curr.id, permission: curr.permission });
        return res;
      }, []);
    })
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-mqncum?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to make recursion

```js
const source = [
  {
    id: 1,
    permission: 2,
    childs: [
      {
        id: 2,
        permission: 1,
        childs: [
          {
            id: 3,
            permission: 3,
            childs: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    permission: 1,
    childs: [
      {
        id: 5,
        permission: 2,
        childs: [
          {
            id: 6,
            permission: 3,
            childs: [
              {
                id: 7,
                permission: 1,
                childs: [],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

const result  = [];

const getAllItemsPerChildren = (item) => {
  result.push({ id: item.id, permission: item.permission });
  if (item.childs) {
    return item.childs.map((i) => getAllItemsPerChildren(i));
  }
};

source.forEach((i) => getAllItemsPerChildren(i));

console.log(result)
```

**RXJS SOLUTION**

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dlva1z?file=index.ts

```
const source$ = of({
  data: [],
  last: false,
  check: source,
}).pipe(
  expand((data) =>
    data.last
      ? EMPTY
      : of(data.check).pipe(
          map((currentItem) => {
            const childs = (currentItem as any).flatMap((i) => i?.childs || []);
            return {
              data: currentItem.map((i) => ({
                id: i.id,
                permissions: i.permission,
              })),
              last: !childs?.length,
              check: childs,
            };
          })
        )
  ),
  reduce((acc, items) => [...acc, ...(items as any).data], [])
);
source$.subscribe((data) => console.log('result ', data));
```

Explanation:

- The main idea to use `expand` operator - it allow us to create recursion.
- To stop recursion need to return `EMPTY`
- `of({data: [],last: false, check: source})` - it is our store
- `data` is assigned to keep parsed item - that will be used in reduce operator - to concat the whole data
- **one return from expand equal to one emit**
- `last` allows to control recusrion, we are checking if all items is parsed
- `check` - element to parse, intial value set to your entire data

Comment: I know about recursion, and I want to try to reach this point with RxJS operators.

Comment: give me a few mins

Comment: I have added rxjs solution

Comment: it it helps you can mark my anser as correct)

Comment: shortest ever ( based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/71857389/9200941): `from(source).pipe(expand((i) => (i?.childs?.length ? from(i.childs) : EMPTY)),
reduce((a, i) => [...a, { id: i.id, permission: i.permission }], [])).subscribe(console.log);`

Answer (score 2):

A simplified `expand` version, just need to ensure every item is emitted and do some clean up at the end with `map`

working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rxjs-playground-forked-vr0l6s?file=/src/index.js

```
from(data)
  .pipe(
    expand((obj) => {
      return obj.childs && obj.childs.length
        ? from(obj.childs)
        : EMPTY;
    }),
    map(obj=>({ id: obj.id, permission: obj.permission })),
    toArray()
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

very good article explains `expand` usage https://ncjamieson.com/understanding-expand/

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a tree (= your data structure) traversal and for every node you have to push `{id://some id,permission://some permission}` on a result array.

You don't need rxjs for that.

Comment: do you mean something like this:

let final = [];
const flatArr = (arr: any[]) => {
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    final.push({ id: item.id, permission: item.permission });
    if (item.childs.length > 0) flatArr(item.childs);
  });
};

Comment: The answer above does exactly what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71856452/2976617